# How can i UPDATE a sql field with a variable instead of a field name?

Tags: php, sql, variables, request

I'm new here (and not english guy, obviously), but I have a problem.
I have a SQL request, it's an `UPDATE` like the following :

```
 $rep = $bdd->exec("UPDATE z_agenda SET AGENDA_1='$code'WHERE AGENDA_NOM='$agent' AND AGENDA_TYPE='code'");
```

BUT, and now the fun is incoming, I want to change `AGENDA_1` to a variable which can contains `AGENDA_1`, `AGENDA_2`, etc. until `AGENDA_31`.
But it seems SQL doesn't like it.
So, anybody has an idea? 
I'm completely stuck right now.

If you want more explanations, I'm here.
*Sit, wait, and read some help forum*

I'm adding some few code : 
"

```
 $mois = $_POST['mois'];   (integer)
    $debut = $_POST['debut'];  (integer : 1-31)
    $lettre = $_POST['lettre'];   (integer)
    $couleur = $_POST['couleur'];   (integer)
    $agent = $_POST['agent'];   (string)
    $code = $lettre + $couleur;

    $rep = $bdd->exec("UPDATE z_agenda
        SET AGENDA_1='$code'
            WHERE AGENDA_NOM='$agent'
            AND AGENDA_TYPE='code'");
```

"

my database contain few information columns, and 31 columns for each day. One line/month/user
don't know how manage my database with an other solution.

Comment: Can you show some more code? Which variable do you what to insert?

Answer (score 0):

There's actually quite a lot going on here.

- you should consider using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to prevent SQL injection vulnerabilities;
- you should read up on [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization);
- you **could** expand the string and add the columns dynamically using, for example, a [for loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) *but you don't want to do this!*

Having numbered columns is usually a Very Bad Idea. Click the database normalization link for detailed information and thorough guidelines on how to proceed. Your application will get unmaintainable with a database structure like this. You'll be writing 'string building loops' for the rest of your life, whereas problems like the one you're having now have been solved a million times before.

Comment: it's for a calendar for my society. i have to manage all users in a same html page, i tryied some things, but i could only success with this...

Comment: You can find loads of information online on how to model a calendar database (even here on StackOverflow). Probably a table `calendar_entries` with the fields `description` and `date` would suffice for you / for now. You can then store as many events as you like, on any given date, without having to bother which column it belongs to.

Comment: With your current design, imagine having to change the date of an event. You'd have to do something like this: `UPDATE z_agenda SET AGENDA_1 = NULL, AGENDA_2 = 'event' WHERE x = y` or something ... Very inconvenient.

Comment: Hi, i just update my post.
I actually have to do a calendar for 75 users, month by month (a full month in a single page), so i didn't know how to do in other way...
But i'll see what you showed to me.

Comment: Well, doesn't help me in my situation :p

Comment: It sure does. You'd have another column 'user_id' in which you can store the user for which the event is planned.

Answer (score -1):

The loop is static just for an example but you can set the inner code into your accordingly

```
for($i=0;$i<=31;$i++)
{
    $agenda_coloumn = 'AGENDA_'.$i;
    $rep = $bdd->exec("UPDATE z_agenda SET $agenda_coloumn = '$code' WHERE AGENDA_NOM='$agent' AND AGENDA_TYPE='code'");
}
```

Comment: You're now executing 31 queries ... And I think with matters like these, you should _always_ inform the poster that he has chosen a very dodgy path.

Comment: @Sherlock i have clearly mentioned in the first line that the loop is just for an example to show him how he can create dynamic column in the query and stated him to use the inner code according to his requirements